# Ideas to Get Rid of a Triple Nested For-Loop in Python?

Tags: python, nested

I have this chunk of code and am relatively new to Python. Any ideas of how to make this more efficient?

```
for i in range(len(snCoords)):
    for j in range(len(snCoords[i])):
        for k in range(len(snCoords[i][j])):
            distances2D[i].append(math.dist(centerPoints[i][j], snCoords[i][j][k]))
```

I tried to use list comprehension, but I'm not sure how that would work with 3 loops.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: I don't think there's a good shortcut for looping over nested iterables like this.

Comment: Does `distances2D` already have stuff in it before you start ? If not, try re-writing the innermost loop as a list comprehension first, then work your way out.

Comment: @ckhan It does not have stuff in it before I start! I will try this approach ty :)

Comment: You might improve efficiency through [vectorization](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html). The effect of vectorization is highly dependent on the data, particularly the size, so it's probably not beneficial if your data are small. But, Euclidean distance should lend itself well to vectorization.

Comment: Define "more efficient". As Barmar pointed using `enumerate` in place of `range(len())` will be more efficient and more idiomatic.

Comment: What does your data, `snCoords` look like? Please provide a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Just use numpy...

Comment: @wim What aspects of numpy did you have in mind?

Comment: @wim Also the arrays are ragged so it won't let me cast as numpy arrays :')

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip to avoid all those index manipulations but there will be 3 levels of looping no matter how you approach this:

```
for dist,cp0,sn0 in zip(distance2D,centerPoints,snCoords):
    dist.extend( math.dist(cp1,sn2) for cp1,sn1 in zip(cp0,sn0)
                                    for sn2 in sn1)
```

Alternatively, if these structures were numpy arrays, there would be no for-loops/comprehensions at all.

Comment: This was very helpful thank you! Additionally they are ragged arrays, but is it worth reshaping them and converting to np.arrays?

Comment: Depends on the total size and scarcity and on how you use the data afterward.  You may need to experiment.  If you are legitimately iterating over theses structures later on, numpy will exact a price (for type conversions) that may offset calculation speed benefits.  Also, if the ratio of empty/used coordinates is high, numpy may not bring substantial improvements despite its parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be re-written as:

```
for i in range(len(snCoords)):
    distances2D[i].extend( math.dist(....)
         for j in range(...)
         for k in range(...))
```